# How do I pass a variable to every controller after a user is authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a system that is segmented into yearly sessions.  A user can go and change the session to see past sessions

How would I go about passing the users current `yearId` to every controller?

I was thinking that I could set a users cookie on authentication or when they manually change their session and check the cookie using a global filter like so

```
public class MyTestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];

        //do something with cookie.Value
        if (cookie!=null) 
        {
           filterContext.ActionParameters["YearId"] = cookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
           // do something here
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Here's how I'd use the above filter: (or add it as a global filter)

```
[MyTestAttribute]
public ActionResult Index(int yearId)
{
    //Pass the yearId down the layers
    // _repo.GetData(yearId);
    return View();
}
```

With this approach, I would have to add yearId to every controller.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: set the variable into session

Comment: I think he can't (or I don't understand the first line)

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using session state

Comment: And what is actually the question? It seems that your approach is ok. Instead of marking all controllers you can write some base class, but there is similar number of characters to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a base class for your Controllers that need the parameter as opposed to the filter:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];

        //do something with cookie.Value
        if (cookie!=null) 
        {
           filterContext.ActionParameters["YearId"] = cookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
           // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could even create a strongly-typed property and make it lazy, so that you don't have to include it as a parameter to every action method and don't perform the evaluation unless you access the property:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    private int? _yearId;

    protected int YearId
    {
        get
        {
             // Only evaluate the first time the property is called
             if (!_yearId.HasValue)
             {
                 // HttpContext is accessible directly off of Controller
                 HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];

                 //do something with cookie.Value
                 if (cookie!=null) 
                 {
                      _yearId = int.Parse(cookie.Value);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      // do something here
                 }
             }

             return _yearId.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to give this a try it sounds like it may work for my situation

Answer (score 0):

That's way too much overhead.

Why not put the value in the session?  If they change the 'session' to see a past one, just modify the variable in the session.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using session state

Comment: You could store current year in a database and do a look up to see what the current year is set as.

Comment: In that case, your approach is good.  Using session just prevents having to retrieve the yearId on every request.  If you don't want that, you don't have many other options (besides getting the data from the db as suggested above).

Comment: @Rick B how to store it in session?

Comment: @Bhushan There are a lot of ways it could be done depending on the application.  The simplest being directly upon login or when the yearId changes - `Session["yearId"] = value`