# How do you store a variable across a system is ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm kind of new to asp.net mvc and I am building a site that is multilingual but I don't want to keep passing around a LanguageId to every constructor of every object that is language specific.  What is the best way to store this Id in asp.net mvc across the entire system?  I believe that for a user, it gets stored in a cookie but is that the right way to go?

Also the languageId is coming from the database and all the language specific labels are also stored in the database not in a resource file

Comment: Take a look at this answer for a similar question that I had http://stackoverflow.com/a/14525189/1152517

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I'd have to disagree with Darin (as in multi-threaded multi server environments, this could pose issues).

I'd recommend a cookie for this, easily picked up when a user enters your site again after a previous visit.

Answer (score 0):

If your Logins are Session driven, you can store your `language-id` in a Session Object. This object could be populated everytime the user logs in. If session is lost, so is the Login.

If you are using Cookie Logins, store the `language-id` in a cookie.

Alternatively, consider making LanguageID part of your route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "New",
    "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { lang = "en|de|it|es|fr" }
);
```

As soon as the user logs in, redirect to a route that includes language as part of the route. use `@Url.actionlink` to render your links. They will always include the language id.

Answer (score 0):

What about taking a slightly different approach for your specific problem, and using the browser language, which  is available via [HttpRequest.UserLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx)?

Then there is no need to pass anything around, as you can get this wherever you can get the `Request` object e.g. in your controllers, it would be `Request.UserLanguages`